# Imports in Python editable local project installs

Tags: python, pip, dependencies, python-poetry

I have a Python project (the parent project) that should use two other local Python projects (the library projects) via editable installs as dependencies (see the corresponding [PEP](https://peps.python.org/pep-0660/), [pip](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/topics/local-project-installs/) and [setuptools](https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/development_mode.html) docs for more info).
However, I have issues making imports within the library projects work.

My project structure is as follows:

```
├── poetry.lock
├── pyproject.toml
└── src
    ├── lib_bar
    │   ├── lib_bar
    │   │   ├── bar.py
    │   │   ├── helper.py
    │   │   └── __init__.py
    │   ├── poetry.lock
    │   └── pyproject.toml
    ├── lib_foo
    │   ├── lib_foo
    │   │   ├── foo.py
    │   │   ├── helper.py
    │   │   └── __init__.py
    │   ├── poetry.lock
    │   └── pyproject.toml
    └── main.py
```

I'm using [Poetry](https://python-poetry.org/) to manage dependencies, and the parent's `pyproject.toml` looks like this:

```ini
[tool.poetry]
name = "multi-editable-dependencies"
version = "0.1.0"
description = ""
authors = ["Your Name <you@example.com>"]
packages = [{include = "src"}]

[tool.poetry.dependencies]
python = "^3.11"
lib_foo = { path = "./src/lib_foo/", develop = true }
lib_bar = { path = "./src/lib_bar/", develop = true }

[build-system]
requires = ["poetry-core"]
build-backend = "poetry.core.masonry.api"
```

and `lib_foo/pyproject.toml` looks like this:

```ini
[tool.poetry]
name = "lib-foo"
version = "0.1.0"
description = ""
authors = ["Your Name <you@example.com>"]
packages = [{include = "lib_foo"}]

[tool.poetry.dependencies]
python = "^3.11"

[build-system]
requires = ["poetry-core"]
build-backend = "poetry.core.masonry.api"
```

(analogously for `lib_bar/pyproject.toml`)

Inside `main.py` I can import from both `lib_foo` and `lib_bar` like this:

```py
from lib_foo.foo import do_main_foo
from lib_bar.bar import do_main_bar

do_main_foo()
do_main_bar()
```

The issue is that with this setup, local imports within the library projects do not work.
With `lib_foo/foo.py` looking like this:

```py
from helper import do_foo

def do_main_foo():
    do_foo()
```

and `lib_foo/helper.py` like this:

```py
def do_foo():
    print("foo")
```

and analogously for `lib_bar` (replacing `foo` with `bar` everywhere), I'm getting errors when I try to run `main.py` via `poetry run python src/main.py` from the parent's root directory:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<parent>/src/main.py", line 8, in <module>
    from lib_foo.foo import do_main_foo
  File "<parent>/src/lib_foo/lib_foo/foo.py", line 1, in <module>
    from helper import do_foo
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'helper'
```

I tried a couple of different solutions that all don't work or are unsatisfactory in different ways.

### Modifying the path

I can fix this error by adding the project roots of the library projects to the path using the following code inside `main.py`:

```py
sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(__file__) + "/lib_foo/lib_foo/")
sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(__file__) + "/lib_bar/lib_bar/")
```

However, by doing this for both projects, `helper.py` now conflicts, i.e. since `lib_foo`'s `helper.py` appears first on the path, `lib_bar` tries to import from `lib_foo`'s `helper.py` and subsequently I get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<parent>/src/main.py", line 8, in <module>
    from lib_bar.bar import do_main_bar
  File "<parent>/src/lib_bar/lib_bar/bar.py", line 1, in <module>
    from helper import do_bar
ImportError: cannot import name 'do_bar' from 'helper' (<parent>/src/lib_foo/lib_foo/helper.py)
```

### Renaming conflicting imports

The above attempt works if I rename `helper.py` to e.g. `help.py` in only one of the libraries.
However, in the actual libraries I want to build such renaming would lead to some awkward names, and I want to use different combinations of libraries in different parent projects, so I would strongly prefer to be able to use modules within each project with the same names.

### Using relative imports

Instead of using `from helper import do_foo`, I can use `from .helper import do_foo` (and analogously for `lib_bar`), which solves the problem.
However, the actual libraries I'm planning to use will have several levels of nested modules, so I would have to use awkward import constructs like `from ....pkg.subpkg import foo`, which will break every time I'm moving a file.
Therefore, I would like to be able to use absolute imports *within each library project*.

### Summing up

Is there some solution that would allow me to use projects as editable, local installs while using local absolute imports within each project, that allow for modules within each project to have the same names as those in other projects?
I am wondering how normal, non-editable installs accomplish this, and whether there is some way to leverage the same mechanism in this case.

Note that I'm using Poetry here, but I also tested the same setup with Pip, i.e. using `pip install -e src/lib_foo`, with the same issues.